# BlurMaskFilter's behavior is weird in a TextView

Tags: java, android, textview, blur

I have below code:

```
String text = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);
ssb.setSpan(new MaskFilterSpan(new BlurMaskFilter(20, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL)),
            3, 7, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
textView.setText(ssb);
```

This works as expected. Only "**DEFG**" gets blurred.
When I try it again with a new text "ABCDEFGABCDEFGABCDEFGABCDEFG", then things get weird. In this string, as you can see "ABCDEFG" is repeated, and the blur effect is also **repeated** on each "**DEFG**", which I never intended it to be..

If I try with "ABCDEABCDEABCDEABCDEABCDE", every "**DE**" gets blurred.

Again, with "ABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABC", **NOTHING** happens.

From this simple test, I can get the pattern the blur effect is being applied, but what I don't understand is, WHY?

Why does `BlurMaskFilter` work this way?

The reason why I did this silly test first was, I got unexpected results in my app. Some weren't applied and some were applied repeatedly. Even after understanding the pattern with the blur effect, it's really hard to use and almost useless..

In my test, there was the same issue in many other devices too, which include Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge (Android 8.0), Galaxy Note 2 (Android 4.4.2), and emulators. (eg. HTC One 4.3)

Am I missing something here?

Comment: This is really strange. I can reproduce this on every AVD I have, down to KitKat, but it works just fine on my Galaxy S6 Edge and Galaxy S7 devices.

Comment: @MikeM. Oh really? Your S7 works? I thought at least all Samsung's devices had the same issue. That's really odd.. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: Ah-hah! Found the issue. Well, not the very lowest root cause, but why I was observing different behavior on my devices, and the general cause of that behavior. Hardware acceleration. I was doing the tests on my devices with my mobile IDE, which uses a project template that's quite outdated. Anyhoo, it's the hardware acceleration that's causing that. I'm not at all versed in the underlying details, but I would guess that it's heavily caching similar draws, and when you repeat the same `String`, it's just using the first draw over and over again. In any case, this is certainly a bug, I'd say.

Comment: You can work around it, for now, by disabling hardware acceleration, at whichever level is appropriate for you: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel#controlling. Somebody should probably file an issue...

Comment: @MikeM. Thank you very much for pointing that out! You're 'kind of' right about the hardware acceleration. I totally forgot that BlurMaskFilter didn't actually support it. I can't find that part from the official documentation and not sure still it's true for the latest devices, though. But I said 'kind of' because when I turn it off, I also lose the blur effect on shadows, which is enabled by calling `setShadowLayer()`. And I need hardware acceleration for other part of code, so I think there's no perfect solution yet.. :(

Comment: Yeah, I didn't see anything about that in the `BlurMaskFilter` documentation. It might be in one of the developer pages for graphics, somewhere. Honestly, I've never used it, so never had an issue. If you can live without the shadow, you can turn of hardware acceleration on individual `View`s, rather than the entire app, or an entire `Activity`. Otherwise, if it is true that `BlurMaskFilter` just doesn't play nice with hardware acceleration, then there is no "perfect solution", really, unless you roll your own effects.

Comment: @MikeM. I'm not 100% sure, but on the page you just linked here in the comment, I remember there was an explanation related to BlurMaskFilter long time ago. Also you can find many other developers on stackoverflow answered BlurMaskFilter wasn't supported by it (even though not sure it's still the case). Anyway your comments helped me a lot!

Comment: Oh, yeah, on that linked page, it does say that `Paint#setMaskFilter()` isn't supported on any API level, and that's basically all `MaskFilterSpan` does. Anyhoo, no problem. Glad I could help a little, at least. :-) Cheers!

Comment: @MikeM. Gosh, I'm blind... Considering most of Views are using Paint objects under the hood, that still applies today, I guess. Thanks again!